# Is there a way to setup retries / timeouts with `awswrangler.athena.read_sql_query`?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-data-wrangler

Often I am running many long running athena queries with awswrangler and from time to time I receive:

```
ReadTimeoutError: Read timeout on endpoint URL: "None"
```

Sometimes I receive some other error, e.g., incorrect number of bytes received.

Is there a way to tell awswrangler to automatically retry in such a scenarios?